# What is the symbol "&" called in Spanish?

Tags: vocabulario, ortografía, símbolos

The symbol `&` is a representation of the Latin word *et* (see DPD, [Appendix 4](http://buscon.rae.es/dpd/apendices/apendice4.html)). Wikipedia [claims](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/%26) that the symbol itself is called *et*; however, the DRAE's entry for [et](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltGUIBusUsual?LEMA=et&origen=RAE) doesn't list the symbol as a meaning of the word, and I have never heard anybody use it in that way.

Which would be a proper name for that symbol?

Comment: Neither **et** nor **ampersand** (which is a direct english translation) exist in DRAE with that meaning. I think the best name is *et*, but I had never heard of it. So I asked if a better name exist.

Comment: I'd say that "&" is not often used in "Spanish sentences". weusually see it inames of International companies or sentences from English. I think that it is because in English "and" is longer than "&" so you save space, but in Spanish "y" is shorter and easier to type/write than "&".

Comment: My large Oxford dictionary translates *ampersand* as *el signo &*, which isn't very helpful.

Comment: Sometimes we call it  'la "y" inglesa'

Comment: Between people who don't know his name is called **"El símbolo de y"** (the symbol of and).

Comment: A quick way to find answers like this is to go to the english wikipedia page for ampersand and click the "espanol" link under languages in the left side bar. It takes you here: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/%26

Answer (score 19):

Based on my personal experience (computer engineering, lots of "&" in programming), I'd say that if you have to name that symbol and want others to understand you while spelling out loud, you have to say "ampersand". Remember that although RAE is the so-called authority, they don't always represent real use. That's why they're constantly upgrading.

Comment: +1 I also use "ampersand" at work

Comment: Yep, the same in Argentina, just *ampersand* with a stress in the first *A*

Comment: Yes, as Petruza stated, technically it would be pronounced as "ámpersand" but I didn't dare writing it because is not a spanish word.

Comment: Curious, in Spain I mostly hear that pronounced "ampersánd".

Comment: The RAE tries to represent real use in the whole hispanic world. Not only in Spain. The fact that ampersand is used in Spain doesn't mean it is used in the rest of the hispanic world. 'Real use' concerns all countries.

Answer (score 17):

[Wikipedia](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/&) has a very clear explanation:

> El signo **&**, cuyo nombre en español es ***et*** es una alternativa gráfica
>   de la conjunción copulativa latina *et*, que significa y de la que
>   deriva la española «y».
>
> Es conocido por su nombre en inglés *ampersand*, proveniente a su vez de
>   la expresión *and per se and*, es decir, «y por sí mismo, y», usada como
>   parte de la retahíla para la memorización del alfabeto.
>
> Deriva del latín de donde el signo pasó a diversos idiomas, incluido
>   el español. Su uso en nuestra lengua es superfluo, pues no resulta
>   económico (a diferencia de otros idiomas) ya que la conjunción
>   copulativa **y** tiene una grafía más breve y sencilla. En textos
>   españoles antiguos es frecuente encontrarlo empleado en la expresión
>   latina adoptada *et cetera*, en las formas *&c.* o *&cetera*.

RAE has this for **et:**

> conj. desus. y.

I'd say *&* is called *et* as Wikipedia points out although is read as `y` just as in English is read as `and`

[Lista de símbolos o signos no alfabetizables](http://www.rae.es/diccionario-panhispanico-de-dudas/apendices/simbolos-o-signos-no-alfabetizables) from RAE (thanks, Javi)

Comment: @Icarus, the point of the question (as it stands now) is that although Wikipedia has an explanation it is unsourced and doesn't seem to be consistent with resources which are considered *the* authority on the subject. This answer doesn't really address that issue.

Comment: @PeterTaylor: OP is asking for the meaning of & and the meaning is clearly `y` (and); The symbol itself is called `et` as shown on the link from RAE posted by Javi and on the question itself. I don't know what else can I do/add to answer the question.

Comment: No, he's asking for the name (which isn't the same as the meaning: in English the name is *ampersand* and the meaning is *and*); similarly the table from DPD (which I linked in the question when I edited it) is a table of meanings, not of names.

Comment: @Icarus -1 I have to agree with Peter. This does not answer the question as the question is how is it called not about what it means and its origins (although its origins are a bonus nice fact) but irrelevant to answer what is asked.

Answer (score 4):

My Gran Diccionario Larousse is also very unhelpful with this.

When I look up English *ampersand* it lists merely: signo "&" - and it has no entry for *et*.

Wiktionary though lists both *[et](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/et#Spanish)* and also [*y comercial*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/y_comercial), both having feminine gender.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the official name is `et` but in the real world, at least in Mexico, this is a symbol very related to the English language. Since `et` is `and` shortened the translation to Spanish is `y`, this makes that in spoken language is usual to say:

> i inglesa. ("ee" pronunciation for i)

Literally *English i*.

If you find out that people doesn't understand you while saying *et* you can try this.

Answer (score 3):

In Dominican Republic we call it "y comercial" since in spanish "y" means "and"

Answer (score 3):

In Colombia and Ecuador and Peru and Venezuela we have always used `e comercial` (pronunciation, `et comercial` written). In Mexico, Cuba and the Dominican Republic I've seen them use `y comercial` In Spain as @Hnavarro said they use `ampersand`.

In my humble opinion `e comercial` is more adapted to the Spanish language. `Ampersand` is more English and mostly used in engineering environments, not in everyday life.

To summarize, I think `e comercial` is a more globally recognized term seeing it in terms of how many countries widely use it in the Hispanic world.

Answer (score 2):

Its Spanish name is officially “*et*”, like the Latin word meaning “and”:

> *En español no se recomienda usar el et pues la conjunción ‘y’ ya es lo suficiente breve y clara, y hasta más fácil de escribir*
>
> (The usage of the ampersand is not recommended in Spanish as the conjunction “*y*” is already brief & clear enough, and even easier to write.)

Comment: "No se recomienda usar" is fine, except when the topic is computer languages.  If the syntax requires an ampersand, then an ampersand is going to be used.  People are going to continue to borrow the English name until something else replaces that.

Answer (score 2):

Though the DLE does not mention the symbol explicitly, other sources from the RAE affirm that the symbol is called *et* in Spanish:

> [#RAEconsultas](https://twitter.com/hashtag/RAEconsultas?src=hash) El signo & se llama «et», pues nace de la ligadura de las letras «e» y «t», que en latín forman la conjunción «et» (= «y»).
>
> - [@RAEinforma](https://twitter.com/raeinforma/status/428144951478988800)
>   4:38 AM - 28 Jan 2014

> **Símbolos o signos no alfabetizables**
> ...
>
> | & | et (*lat.:* y) |
> | --- | --- |
>
> - [*Diccionario panhispánico de dudas » Apéndices » Símbolos o signos no alfabetizables*](http://www.rae.es/diccionario-panhispanico-de-dudas/apendices/simbolos-o-signos-no-alfabetizables)

> > #### &, nombre de este signo gráfico
> >
> > ¿Qué nombre recibe el signo gráfico «&» que aparece en los teclados?
>
> En español se llama *et* y en inglés *ampersand*.
>
> - [*Fundéu BBVA*](https://www.fundeu.es/consulta/nombre-de-este-signo-grafico-2714/)

Answer (score 0):

This is a nice question because symbols and abbreviations denote a shorthand for a word(s). Such cases often lead to a lack of translation in any language because these symbols are language context independent ( another example being the $ symbol) (counter examples exist for symbols such as the caret symbol, etc.) According to the historic root, & was used as a short form for et (latin for the word and). Feel free to use "ampersand" or "et" as per your convenience.

Comment: That does not seem to add anything to the previous answers can you expand it, perhaps with references?

Answer (score 0):

---

Que tal? Nombre de "&" como "*y comercial*"

El carácter &, llamado et ó también como **y comercial**, es una ligadura de la conjunción copulativa latina «et» y equivale a la conjunción Española «y».

Pensé que este dato sería interesante. Saludos.

Diego M.