# ¿Cómo se puede traducir el catalán "nostrat" al castellano?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, adjetivos

En catalán tenemos el adjetivo [*nostrat*](http://www.diccionari.cat/lexicx.jsp?GECART=0094675) para definir cosas que son propias de aquello de lo que se está hablando, en el sentido cuasi folclórico:

> Aquell restaurant fa menjar molt *nostrat*.

Se podría traducir como:

> Ese restaurante sirve comida muy X.

Donde *X* denotaría que es comida muy propia de la zona, por ejemplo con recetas que todas nuestras abuelas hacían de forma exquisita y que no se encuentran en otras zonas.

Su etimología viene del latín *nostras*, que quiere decir [*nuestros compatriotas*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/nostratic). *Nostre* es como se dice *nuestro* en catalán y supongo que también comparte con el italiano *nostra* (de la *Cosa Nostra*, por ejemplo), todo ello queriendo decir lo propio a nosotros.

Dado que el adjetivo es muy útil y tiene una connotación bonita, me planteo: ¿existe alguno equivalente en castellano? Decir "comida muy nuestra" parece la tradución rápida, pero me pregunto si alguna otra.

Comment: Existe la palabra *castizo* (típico, genuino del país o del lugar en cuestión); aunque el DRAE aconseja aplicarlo solo a personas, lo he visto aplicado a otras cosas. Pero no me atrevo a aconsejarlo porque tiene unas connotaciones demasiado fuertes.

Comment: Creo que *muy nuestra* funciona bien: también se puede decir —y se oye con frecuencia— usar *suyo* en este mismo correo texto para decir muy propio de aquella persona o entidad. La única diferencia con *suyo* y *nuestro* es la diferencia de a quién pertenece el estilo.

Comment: @guifa de todos modos cuando oigo que alguien es _muy suyo_ eso lleva aparejado una connotación negativa que _nostrat_ no tiene (más bien al contrario).

Comment: Esa frase sirve cuando hablas de un restaurante tipico de la zona actual si el hablante no pertenece a ella? (por ejemplo si vas a un restaurante que sirve comida tipica vasca en el pais vasco)

Comment: @BrianH. sí, efectivamente.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Dado que quieres decir "muy nuestra" (que me parece la mejor opción y totalmente válida), "muy **propia** de nuestra cultura o **región**"  puedes *forzar* [autóctono](http://dle.rae.es/?id=4RuA840) (`originado en el mismo lugar donde se encuentra`) o [vernáculo/la](http://dle.rae.es/?id=beZBwV4)  (`Doméstico, nativo, de la casa o país propios`).

Decir "muy nuestra" para mí no es solo "la traducción más rápida" sino la mejor. Transmite el concepto mejor que las otras opciones, que podrían asociarse a una región en lugar de a una cultura. Por ejemplo, si estuvieses visitando junto a otros catalanes Londres/Tokyo/San Diego y hubiese un restaurante de (auténtica) comida catalana, decir "muy nuestra" expresaría "muy catalana" (auténtica; muy propia de la cultura de los que somos de este grupo), mientras que mis otras propuestas podrían interpretarse como "muy de aquí", de este lugar (en el que somos extranjeros).

---

Actualización: paseando hoy por Madrid me he encontrado con esto, y me he acordado de ti. "**Muy nuestro**".

[image]

Comment: @walen, no pasa nada hombre. Si estuviese revisando las "late answers" y encontrase una nueva _muy parecida_ a una muy antigua sí que pondría un comentario a un usuario, pero dado que estamos respondiendo y editando a la vez (y dado además que la propuesta de la propia pregunta parece ser la mejor opción) es de lo más normal.

Comment: En Chile, y me imagino que en el resto de América, dado que diferenciamos entre la población criolla (con alguna fracción de genética y cultura europea) y la población nativa, no nos sirve _autóctona_ como sinónimo de "típica".

Comment: Qué gracia que usen el [et](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/1072/1674) inglés y luego hablen de _muy nuestro_ :))

Answer (score 6):

Aplicado a la comida se me ocurren: [*típica*](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?w=t%C3%ADpica), [*tradicional*](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?w=tradicional), [*regional*](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?w=regional). Todas ellas más o menos cuadran con la descripción que has dado: un adjetivo para algo que es particular de la zona y/o con raíces en las costumbres del lugar.

Pasando a expresiones, [*de la tierra*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Zj5UJym#ADiNsl4) o *de la abuela* también podrían valer.

Eso sí: ninguna encajará nunca tan exactamente como ***nuestra***, porque ésta además tiene la misma connotación que *nostrat* de incluir al que habla dentro de ese conjunto de tradiciones.

Yo puedo usar "tradicional" para hablar de las *kokotxas* que me han puesto en Bilbao; pero no tendría sentido que usara "nuestra", ni *nostrat*, porque yo no soy de Bilbao.
Cuando alguien te dice que la comida de un sitio es "muy nuestra", no solo te está diciendo que la comida es tradicional: también te está diciendo que esa tradición es la suya propia.

Comment: "De la abuela" es una frase bonita.

Comment: Si quieres incluir al que habla en la expresión, puedes cambiar "de la tierra" por "de mi tierra", sobre todo si el que habla no se encuentra _en su tierra_ en ese momento.

Comment: Tras ver la respuesta a mi comentario a la pregunta opino que esta debería ser la respuesta aceptada, tienes mi +1 :)